im using pi4 and i need to connect firwmware using serial port ,im using the path /dev/serial0 ,uart gets open but then im getting this error
UART port opened
[8874:1217/124133.787312:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.798357:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.802822:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.803787:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.810197:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.815570:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.820264:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.826509:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.828134:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.830565:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.834921:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.837988:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.840619:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.843237:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.870717:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.871920:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.873069:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.873784:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.874871:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.875402:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.877987:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.883165:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.893216:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.894967:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.898665:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.899346:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.900871:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[8874:1217/124133.902408:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
^C/home/dell/intenship/homing/new-for_motor/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGINT
dell@raspberrypi:~/intenship/homing/new-for_motor $ npx electron .
UART port opened
[9125:1217/124248.310425:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.311327:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.311967:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.312244:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.312740:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.312993:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.313529:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.315796:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.317201:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.319855:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.322866:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.323675:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.325097:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.329860:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.343816:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.344299:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.345171:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.346057:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.347765:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.348522:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.349331:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.350005:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.351429:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.352273:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.354860:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.356029:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.358237:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(79)] Failed to get fd for plane.: No such file or directory (2)
[9125:1217/124248.358886:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(262)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
im using electron and there is main.js which is the entry point ,on main.js i wrote
process.env.ELECTRON_DISABLE_GPU = '1'; but still getting same error..im having an api to start the motor that api needed to give it to the firmware ,its not recieving due to this error
